# Thymleaf is rendering german characters as questionmarks

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

When using Spring with Thymeleaf all my special German characters are shown as `?????` on pages.

I have already tried to add an template resolver with encoding to `utf-8` like [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#more-on-configuration)

do you have any clues?

Comment: you should paste the view resolver configuration and other related code, so i can help you

Comment: Its not thymeleaf, its your encoding. Check page encoding - and if you got proper letters in page content as well.

Comment: And double check that the characters are still OK in the string you output to see if the problem happens on input or on output.

Comment: Thymleaf use data from database? Or? Paste more information

Comment: The common issues are already listed: a.) If the characters are stored in a db -> check the db-charset b.) check your template encoding (the encoding your editor uses).

Comment: i have figured out the problem. 
here is the solution and reason: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/713